# How do I output all rows of MySQL table and include a column for counting duplicates?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I have found questions related to removing duplicates and counting duplicates, but I haven't been able to add a duplicate count to MySQL rows, so I pose this question.  Here's what I have so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Losers ORDER BY Date DESC"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<table>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['Name']. "</td><td>". date("l, M j, Y",strtotime($row['Date'])) . '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
mysql_close($con);
```

Now I want to include a count of the duplicates in Name for each row.  So, it would read something like this:

```
Ben 2
Laura 3
Amy 1
Laura 3
Ben 2
Laura 3
```

I found a this query to group duplicates in Name and count them:

```
$newQuery = "SELECT Name, Date, COUNT(Name) FROM Losers GROUP BY Name";
```

But then it will output:

```
Ben 2
Laura 3
Amy 1
```

How do I incorporate both queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, you can't do that without a subquery:

```
SELECT Losers.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Losers AS Sub WHERE Sub.Name = Losers.Name) AS `count` FROM Losers ORDER BY Date DESC
```

But personally, I'd rather do that with two separate queries instead.

**Edit:** see the two answers below, they're much better.

Comment: This would get exponentially slow as a function of entries in `Losers` table.

Comment: Not to brag, but my answer or Basti's is better since the subquery will only be run once ;)

Comment: You're right. In fact I didn't even know that JOIN (SELECT...) is a valid statement. Stupid me )

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Losers.Name, Losers.Date, L.Count
FROM Losers
JOIN (
    SELECT Name, COUNT( Name ) AS Count
    FROM Losers
    GROUP BY Name
) AS L ON Losers.Name = L.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is probably to take your query with the GROUP BY clause and use it as a subquery that you join to your original table.

I.E.

```
SELECT L.*, Loser_Count.count
FROM Losers L
JOIN (SELECT loser_id, COUNT(Name) count FROM Losers GROUP BY Name) Loser_Count ON
  L.loser_id = Loser_Count.loser_id 
ORDER BY L.date DESC
```

This should work, but I wouldn't be surprised if a SQL genius comes back with a more efficient way. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in two **separate** queries:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) FROM Losers GROUP BY Name
/* Parse this to have a php array $l_count in form ("Ben" => 2, "Laura" => 3) */
SELECT Name FROM Losers

while ($name = mysql_fetch...) {
    print $name.' '.$l_count[$name]."\n";
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Using SQL

```
SELECT field 1, field 2, field 3, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY field 1, field 2, field 3
```

That SQL will give you all distinct rows, and an output of # of times they show up

Comment: And that is exactly what he did and did not want to have.